# Trying to build a iterative columni in python pandas with conditional formulas

Tags: python, pandas, recursion, conditional-statements

I am new on Python and Stack overflow I am trying to buind a column in pandas that depends on previous values and conditional values of other columns and I get an error. I've build some simple formulas with those criteria but when I try to build something more complex it does not work. How can I do that? thanks
I AMMENDED THE CODE As PER comments below ​

```
df["tr-resist1"]= df["tr-resist"]

df["tr-supp1"]= df["tr-supp"]

​

for i in range(8, len(df)):

        if df.loc(i,"Initial_linetype").shift(1)== "Resist":

            df.loc[i,"tr-resist"] = min(df["EMA_MP"]+df['ATR']/2+df["stdATR"]*7,df.loc["tr-resist"].shift(1))

            df.loc[i,"tr-supp1"] =  df["EMA_MP"]-df['ATR']/2-df["stdATR"]*7

            if df.loc[i,"Close"]>df.loc[i,"tr-resist1"]:

                df[i,"Initial_linetype"]= "Supp"

            else: 

                df[i,"Initial_linetype"]= "Resist"

        else: 

            df.loc[i,"tr-supp1"] = max(df.loc["tr-supp1"].shift(1),df.loc[i, "tr-supp"])

            df.loc[i,"tr-resist1"] = df["EMA_MP"]-df['ATR']/2-df["stdATR"]*7        

            if df.loc[i,"Close"]<df.loc[i,"tr-supp1"]:

                    df[i,"Initial_linetype"]= "Resist"

            else: 

                    df[i,"Initial_linetype"]= "Supp"

​

df.tail()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-339bc8cd24cf> in <module>
      5 
      6 for i in range(8, len(df)):
----> 7         if df.loc(i,"Initial_linetype").shift(1)== "Resist":
      8             df.loc[i,"tr-resist"] = min(df["EMA_MP"]+df['ATR']/2+df["stdATR"]*7,df.loc["tr-resist"].shift(1))
      9             df.loc[i,"tr-supp1"] =  df["EMA_MP"]-df['ATR']/2-df["stdATR"]*7

TypeError: __call__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Maybe you meant to use [ instead of ( in your iloc and you're missing the closing ]  make it look like the one a few lines below

Comment: I think as well that @Chris comment is your answer. I also would like to suggest you to take a look at pandas docs and review the methods and functions... It would really help you. I believe your code can be simplified a lot. e.g. you are working with `i-1` and `i` indexes within a loop, where you can use `.shift()` method and write operations column wise. pandas is much faster if you don't loop manually over rows

Comment: thanks....I adjusted the code to use shift but still get the same problem